# Unity Firebase DLL files not being found in Standalone build of the game

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, dll

I am working on a game that needs user registration and I decided to go with Firebase for that, and while the Firebase DLL's work fine in the editor version of the game and are found, but in the standalone build the DLL's aren't found at all, I have already tried re-installing the Firebase packages from the package manager but still nothing. Any help appreciated, thanks! (Standalone build log included below)

````
Mono config path = 'C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Initialize engine version: 2020.3.0f1 (c7b5465681fb)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER (ID=0x1e84)
    Vendor:   (null)
    VRAM:     3072 MB
    Driver:   27.21.14.6140
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Completed reload, in  1.467 seconds
D3D11 device created for Microsoft Media Foundation video decoding.
<RI> Initializing input.

<RI> Input initialized.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

UnloadTime: 0.872100 ms
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0.dll
Fallback handler could not load library C:/Users/xisso/typistNew/Builds/typist_Data/Mono/libFirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil(Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x000ee] in <efce830506c14731bd3b7a14d631487d>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
  at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE..cctor () [0x00000] in <efce830506c14731bd3b7a14d631487d>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogUtil+LogMessageDelegate arg0) [0x00000] in <efce830506c14731bd3b7a14d631487d>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..ctor () [0x0001e] in <efce830506c14731bd3b7a14d631487d>:0 
  at Firebase.LogUtil..cctor () [0x00010] in <efce830506c14731bd3b7a14d631487d>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.LogUtil' threw an exception.
  at Firebase.FirebaseApp..cctor () [0x0004a] in <efce830506c14731bd3b7a14d631487d>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.FirebaseApp' threw an exception.
  at FirebaseManager+<CheckAndFixDependancies>d__13.MoveNext () [0x00029] in <683734d3b77f42af9b02e4732380236e>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00026] in <2adb6344b47640a2b062486ecba39524>:0 
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2(IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
FirebaseManager:Start()

Setting up 4 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 67c8 -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 2ab4 -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 6824 -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 3888 -> priority: 1 ```
````

Comment: This is an issue that's occurred at least once before without being resolved ( https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/923 ). If you wouldn't mind logging a report over there and helping the team work through it, it would be awesome.

My recommended course of action would be to copy all the missing DLLs out of your Assets/ directory and into the same directory as your generated EXE, although this should happen automatically. Also check your generated executable maybe x64 vs x86 matters for instance? Or UWP vs standard desktop (I don't think Firebase makes WinRT dlls)?

Comment: Check the answer for what I did for solution, thank you for the idea I would have not thought of switching the type of executable!

Answer (score 2):

Update: I found out that setting my build architecture from x86 to x86_64. I still don't know exactly why x86 alone doesn't work and seem to generate/find the dll's but the problem seems to be fixed for now.